# Search local Excel files from webpage

Tags: php, html, excel

I’ve got multiple Excel files stored on my PC, I’ve been looking for a PHP script to handle a form in a local HTML file to search the Excel for certain data (Such as name + surname etc.)

Here’s the form in the HTML

```
<FORM Method="POST" Name="f"
      Action="search.php">

<TABLE BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="8" RULES="groups"
       BORDERCOLOR="#DDD6E4" BGCOLOR="#F5F5F5">

<TBODY>
<TR><TD>
<SELECT NAME="srch1v" ID="SEL1" OnChange="SelProc(this, 'OPT1', 'SRCH1', 0)">
<OPTION VALUE="">Data Type
<OPTION VALUE="S" SELECTED>Surname
<OPTION VALUE="G">GivenName
<OPTION VALUE="T">Town
<OPTION VALUE="X">Any Field
</SELECT>

<SELECT NAME="srch1t" ID="OPT1">
<OPTION VALUE="">Search Type
<OPTION VALUE="Q" SELECTED>Phonetically Like
<OPTION VALUE="D">Sounds Like
<OPTION VALUE="S">Starts with
<OPTION VALUE="E">is Exactly
</SELECT>

<INPUT name="srch1" ID="SRCH1" size="25" maxlength="25">
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>

<SELECT NAME="srch2v" ID="SEL2" 

        OnChange="SelProc(this, 'OPT2', 'SRCH2', 0)">
<OPTION VALUE="">Data Type
<OPTION VALUE="S">Surname
<OPTION VALUE="G" SELECTED>GivenName
<OPTION VALUE="T">Town
<OPTION VALUE="X">Any Field
</SELECT>

<SELECT NAME="srch2t" ID="OPT2">
<OPTION VALUE="">Search Type
<OPTION VALUE="Q"  SELECTED>Phonetically Like
<OPTION VALUE="D">Sounds Like
<OPTION VALUE="S">Starts with
<OPTION VALUE="E">is Exactly
</SELECT>
<INPUT name="srch2" ID="SRCH2" size="25" maxlength="25">
</TD></TR>
</TBODY>
```

Can somebody point me where to start?

Comment: I suggest searching for GET/POST requests, then for "parse XLSX file PHP"; that should get you started.

Comment: PHP runs on the server. It cannot read the files on your local (client) machine, unless you also upload the files to the server when you submit the form. Once you've sorted that bit, you can find existing PHP libraries available which can interact with Excel (and other Office) files. Start by choosing one and following its documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a list of the files in a folder in Chrome using this PHP Code

```
<?php
$dir = opendir("Folder"); //Path
while ($files = readdir($dir)) //Obtain files
{
    if (is_dir($files))//Verificate that is a directory
    {
        //echo "[".$files . "]<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<center><a href='Folder/$files' target='_blank'>" .$files. "</a><br /></center>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problems of a) reading the files from the local disk or b) searching **within** the files. Read the question again.